# Tagging media with grouped tags using Neo4j and Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Cypher newbie here.

I made this graph of tagged Media using the code below.

[image: Tagged media]

```
CREATE
(funny:Tag { name: 'Funny' }),
(sad:Tag { name: 'Sad' }),
(movie:Tag { name: 'Movie' }),
(tv:Tag { name: 'TV Show' }),
(hangover:Media { name: 'The Hangover' }),
(koth:Media { name: 'King of the Hill' }),
(simpsons:Media { name: 'The Simpsons' }),
(twm:Media { name: 'Tuesdays with Morrie' }),
(mm:Media { name: 'Mary & Max' }),
(funny)-[:DESCRIBES]->(hangover),
(funny)-[:DESCRIBES]->(koth),
(funny)-[:DESCRIBES]->(simpsons),
(sad)-[:DESCRIBES]->(twm),
(sad)-[:DESCRIBES]->(mm),
(movie)-[:DESCRIBES]->(hangover),
(movie)-[:DESCRIBES]->(twm),
(movie)-[:DESCRIBES]->(mm),
(tv)-[:DESCRIBES]->(koth),
(tv)-[:DESCRIBES]->(simpsons)
```

What I want to do is group Tags together into Contexts, such that one Context node has the same meaning as multiple Tags.

```
MATCH
(tf:Tag { name: 'Funny' }),
(tr:Tag { name: 'Sad' }),
(tm:Tag { name: 'Movie' })
(tt:Tag { name: 'TV Show' })
CREATE
(fm:Context { name: 'Funny Movies' }),
(ft:Context { name: 'Funny TV' }),
(s:Context { name: 'Sad Movies' }),
(fm)-[:INCLUDES]->(tf),
(fm)-[:INCLUDES]->(tm),
(ft)-[:INCLUDES]->(tf),
(ft)-[:INCLUDES]->(tt),
(s)-[:INCLUDES]->(tm),
(s)-[:INCLUDES]->(tr)
```

So now we have this thing.

[image: With Contexts]

I want to take a Context node and get Media such that ALL Tags in that Context describe each returned Media.

I tried `MATCH (c:Context { name: 'Funny Movies' })-[:INCLUDES]->()-[:DESCRIBES]->(m) RETURN m` to match media tagged with both `Funny` and `Movies`. The expected output was only `The Hangover`, but I get all Media instead.

[image: All media]

It's pretty obvious that I don't understand the kind of query I need to write. What is wrong with my query, and how can I produce the output that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start from a context, you can `collect` the tags and then match movies that are related to `ALL` the tags. The highlighted words in the previous sentence are the keywords for you as reference in the neo4j documentation :

```
MATCH (c:Context {name:"Funny Movies"})-[:INCLUDES]->(tag)
WITH collect(tag) AS tags
MATCH (m:Media) WHERE ALL( x IN tags WHERE (x)-[:DESCRIBES]->(m))
RETURN m
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you, and accepted. I thought that specifying exactly one context would filter output to vertices connected only to that context. Since it didn't, what exactly was my original query doing?

Comment: Your query is just following the pattern, translate () to nodes and [] to relationships and you will see that it has 5 patterns to different medias.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bi-directional pattern:

```
MATCH (c:Context { name: 'Funny Movies' })-[:INCLUDES]->()-[:DESCRIBES]
      ->(m)<-
      [:DESCRIBES]-()<-[:INCLUDES]-(c)
RETURN m
```